# Problem producing a new random number at the end of HiLo guessing game

Tags: java, if-statement, random, while-loop, hilo

I'm creating a HiLo guessing game in Java. Everything I have so far works as intended except at the end when I prompt a user to play again, the random number remains the same from the previous game. How do I make it so the code produces a new random number when the user chooses to play a new game?

```
    int answer  = (int)(Math.random() * 100 + 1);
    int guess = 0;
    int guessCount = 0;
    boolean playGame = true;
    String restart;
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    
while(playGame == true)
{
    while (playGame == true) 
    {
        System.out.println("Enter a number between 1 and 100: ");
        guess = scan.nextInt();
        guessCount ++;
        
        System.out.println(answer);
        
        if (guess < 1 || guess > 100) 
        {
            System.out.println("You have entered an invalid number.");
            guessCount --;
        } else if (guess == answer) 
        {
            System.out.println("Correct! Great guess! It took you " + guessCount + " tries!");
            break;
        } else if (guess > answer) 
        {
            System.out.println("You've guessed too high! Guess again: ");
        } else if (guess < answer)
        {
            System.out.println("You've guessed too low! Guess again: ");
        }
    }
    
    System.out.println("Would you like to play again? Y/N");
    restart = scan.next();
    
    if (restart.equalsIgnoreCase("Y")) 
    {
        playGame = true;
    } else if(restart.equalsIgnoreCase("N"))
    {
        System.out.println("Thank you for playing!");
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value in the variable 'answer' remains same since variable is a reference to what you have stored / Initialized or Assigned. It does not manipulate in itself. You have to rewrite the code for e.g. `answer = (int)(Math.random()*100+1)` at the point before game will be restarted or after it.

Comment: I completely overlooked this. I added the value of answer in the first bracket of the while loop and now it works like a charm for anyone having similar issues. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

You're initializing the `answer` before the loop, it never changes. You have to assign `answer` a new value when the user chooses to play a new round. This is not the code I'd write, but here it is:

```
if (restart.equalsIgnoreCase("Y")) 
{
    answer  = (int)(Math.random() * 100 + 1);
}
```